# MapToScreen / ScreenToMap functionality (or similar)

Tags: point, coordinates, geolocation

I need to display latitude/longitude coordinates of the mouse pointer on the map, as the user moves the mouse.

I searched the examples and found this API [Map.ScreenToMap] in an older version of the .NET SDK for WPF, which has been retired.

Is there equivalent/similar functionality in the current Esri.ArcGISRuntime.WPF 100.12.0? Or do I need more than the free developer account for this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I found the new API, it is `MapView.ScreenToLocation(screenPoint)`.
C# code, if anyone is interested:

```
   private void MainMapView_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Point screenPoint = e.GetPosition(MainMapView);
        ScreenCoordsTextBlock.Text = string.Format("Screen Coords: X = {0}, Y = {1}",
                screenPoint.X, screenPoint.Y);

        MapPoint mapPoint = MainMapView.ScreenToLocation(screenPoint);

        if (mapPoint !=null)
        {
            MapCoordsTextBlock.Text = CoordinateFormatter.ToLatitudeLongitude(mapPoint, LatitudeLongitudeFormat.DecimalDegrees, 4);
        }
    }
```